# Why wrong greeting is coming in Java

Tags: java

I wanted to make a program that greets you according to the time of day . I live in India so the zoneid that I used was **Asia/Kolkata** The timezone here is IST(GMT+5:30). And while I am writing this question the time here is 12:49 PM . Still this print the output good night idk what is wrong with the code . THE CODE IS ==

```
LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
int h_today = today.getHour();
if(h_today > 0 && h_today < 12)
     { 
     System.out.println("Good morning ma'am! \n"); 
     }
     else if(h_today > 12 && h_today < 17)
     { 
     System.out.println("Good afternoon ma'am! \n"); 
     }
     else if( h_today >17 && h_today < 23 )
     {
     System.out.println("Good evening ma'am! \n"); 
     }
     else 
     {
      System.out.println("Good night ma'am! \n"); 
     }
```

I used LocalDateTime instead of LocalTime because I need to do some more operations also and I think that shouldn't have affected the output . I think the problem is with the conditions that I gave . Please help me ☆

Comment: You check `> 12` and `< 12`. Neither of those matches 12. Consider using `<=` or `>=`.

Comment: Change your conditions to `if (h_today < 12)`, `else if (h_today < 17)` etc. Simpler conditions, less things to get wrong.

Comment: Thank you both of you both ways are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hour is 12, it is not present in any of the if statements. So the control is going to else. Put >= instead of >.
Change

```
else if(h_today > 12 && h_today < 17)
```

to

```
else if(h_today >= 12 && h_today < 17)
```

similarly for others.

Answer (score 1):

Since you always compare both sides of the interval with `<` or `>` you miss the cases where the value is actually equal.
Also it is kind of redundant, because one side of the interval is already checked by the previous condition, or by the guarantees of `getHour`

I suggest rewriting your condition like this

```
if(h_today < 12) { 
    System.out.println("Good morning ma'am! \n"); 
} else if(h_today < 17) { 
    System.out.println("Good afternoon ma'am! \n"); 
} else if(h_today < 23) {
    System.out.println("Good evening ma'am! \n"); 
} else {
    System.out.println("Good night ma'am! \n"); 
}
```